# CPAN fails to compile C, how can I configure CCFLAGS?

Tags: perl, freebsd, cpan

I have a new FreeBSD 9.0 installation that is having trouble installing modules that require C via CPAN. It seems to be down to `cc` being called without `-I/usr/local/include`. I've tried overriding that by starting CPAN with `INC="-I/usr/local/include"` - while that fixes the problem for some modules, it breaks for others as it seems to be overriding any defaults set in makefiles.

I've got another box with pretty much the same setup on it (slightly older installation, but still FreeBSD 9.0), `perl -V` on the old box shows that `ccflags` contains `-I/usr/local/include`, whereas it doesn't on the new box.

I'm guessing this is why CPAN is calling `cc` without it.

Question is, how can I configure it?

Answer (score 3):

The settings used by CPAN modules come from the Config module which is part of core Perl.  It records the compilation options and settings used when Perl was compiled.

For whatever reason, the person compiling Perl on your new FreeBSD 9.0 installation decided not to include `-I/usr/local/include`.

Fighting the settings in the Config module is hard work, as you've already discovered.  On the whole, it is simplest not to fight it.  If you want Perl to use `/usr/local/include`, then compile Perl so as to do so.  You'll probably want to specify `-l/usr/local/lib` too.

You should check whether the versions of Perl are the same or not on your two similar systems.

Comment: Yes that definitely seems like the way forward, but I haven't been able to work out how yet ;) On both machines Perl is 5.14.2 (the newer is 5.14.2_2 and has a coupla extra FreeBSD-specific patches, but I couldn't see anything that might cause a problem like this). In both cases it was installed from the FreeBSD ports system, with default options (I even tried compiling it again, same situation). Any idea how I can add that option when compiling via ports?

Comment: Since the FreeBSD 'ports' system is news to me — first time I've heard of it — I've no idea, I'm afraid.  I normally hand-configure Perl, fixing the locations where I want them, adding and removing include directories (usually removing `/usr/local/include` in my case; it is normally included by default), and so on.  The 'hand-configure' means 'run the (interactive) Configure script and provide the appropriate values to its questions'.  I never install my builds of Perl in a system directory — I don't want to risk screwing up something that is expecting a different version of Perl.

Answer (score 1):

If it works, your best bet is probably to add it to the `ccflags` entry in the file returned by

```
perl -E'require "Config_heavy.pl"; say $INC{"Config_heavy.pl"};'
```

Otherwise, there is surely a means of specifying this to [ExtUtis::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker) and to [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aBuild) installers. If so, you can set this `cpan` using `o conf makepl_arg` and `o conf mbuildpl_arg`. (Don't forget to commit!)